# how do I create a new project with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I new started use for mac os. While created a new project with create-react-app, I take a that error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! recipe@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the recipe@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macbook/.npm/_logs/2019-08-21T16_25_25_607Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What command did you run that caused this error?

Comment: Does the log give you a hint?

Comment: there might be missing packages. run `npm install` to install all dependencies first and then run the command you ran

Comment: Can you paste the command you ran ?

Comment: I think he ran `npm start` by seeing logs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run:

```
npm install
```

Before you can run:

```
npm start
```